# How to convert number to month name in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

[image]

This is what my dropdown list looks like

[image]

How do I convert the number into a month name?

Because when you sort the data with dropdown user wants to see the month name not the numbers

I used strftime and still getting error.

This is my form which I used to add the data that is the date which is in database:

```
  <form method="POST" id="personForm" data-cities-url="{% url 'users:ajax_load_cities' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group pr-4">
        <legend class="mb-4">Report Form</legend>
            <div class="form-row">
                 <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.area|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.country|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                    {{ form.month|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-row">

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.new_ministers|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.dis_course|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-row">

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.licenced_ministers|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.upgrade_licence|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-row">

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.preaching_place|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.new_churches|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-row">

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.water_baptism|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.holy_ghost|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-row">

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.constituents|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.total_holy_ghost|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-row">

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.total_baptized|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-row">

                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.author }}
                    <p class="text-danger">If you choose wrong name, your info will not be saved</p>
                  </div>

            </div>


    </fieldset>
   <div class="form-group">
     <button style="border-radius: 0; width: 200px; padding-left: 4px;" class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you share your form?

Comment: maybe you should hardwire code it as a fixed list of months, say `["January", "February", ...]` :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added the form above. It was too big for the comments area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom template tag to convert the number to month name. Here is a sample code you can use as a custom tag.

```
from django import template
import calendar

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def month_name(month_number):
    month_number = int(month_number)
    return calendar.month_name[month_number]
```

At first, load your custom tag like this.

```
{% load month_tags %}
```

And use with month field as follows.

```
{{ form.month|month_name }}
```

Comment: No. It is the custom tag file name. In your app create a directory called `templatetags` and add a file called `month_tags.py`. Then load it by the file name.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Calendar API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name)

`calendar.month_name[12]`  will return december.

or

```
import datetime
month = 12
print (datetime.date(1997, month, 1).strftime('%B'))
```

this will show you december as well
:)